# Is the verb "hook" a movement verb?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

See the word "**hook**" in the dictionary

> [hook](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hook) 2 ●○○ verb [transitive]
>
> 1 FISH to catch a fish with a hook
>
> *I hooked a 20-pound salmon last week.*
>
> 2 FASTEN [always + adverb/preposition] to fasten or hang something
> onto something else hook something onto/to something
>
> *Just hook the bucket onto the rope and lower it down.*
>
> 3 BEND YOUR FINGER/ARM ETC [always + adverb/preposition] to bend your
> finger, arm, or leg, especially so that you can pull or hold something
> else
>
> *Ruth hooked her arm through Tony’s.*
>
> *He tried to hook his leg over the branch.*

These are movement verbs:

***I took/ moved / carried... the hat out of the water.***

There are other verbs that you will not do any further action. For example,

You say "***I touched/ grabbed/held the hat***"

But you can not say "***I touched/ grabbed/held the hat out of the water***"

When you look at the third definition, it means "*you put something that looks like a hook in something *so that* you can pull it*".

The dictionary say "**so that you can pull it**". This means the verb "**hook**" doesn't carry the meaning that "**it pulls something**".

And I think "**hook**" is like "**touch**" or "**grab**" or "**hold**" because you just make something like a cane in contact with a hat, for example, but you don't pull the hat.

Suppose you dropped your hat into a river and you used a cane to get it out of the water.

My question is that:

Does the verb "**hook**" mean:

1- "**you just connect the hook to something and you do not move the thing around**"?

or

2- "**you connect the hook to something and you move that thing too**"?

With the fist meaning, we have to say "**I hooked the cane into the hat then took it out of the water**" because the verb "**hook**" does not mean to carry something away.

With the second meaning, we just need to say "**I hooked the hat out of the water**" because the verb "**hook**" includes the meaning of carrying something away.

Comment: I would say "hook" is a movement verb. However what is the significance of a verb being a "movement verb" or "non=movement verb"? You asked the question for a reason. So there is likely some significance to a verb being a movement or no=movement verb. I would like to know that significance.

Comment: @banuyayi I updated my question

Comment: "I grabbed the hat out of the water" is fine, despite what you think. "Hook" is if anything more marginal.

Answer (score 2):

*Hook X* does not automatically mean you are pulling or lifting X unless context strongly implies it.

Valid contexts include:

- fishing
- places or scenarios where fishing is likely or possible
- when you specify something that is a hook or in a hook shape that was used - e.g. "Hooked the hat out of the water with my hand" works - it means you put your hand into a hook shape and used it to catch+lift the hat.

(and yes, *hook X* can also mean to make bendable-rod-like object X into the shape of a hook.)

---

> But you can not say "I touched/ grabbed/held the hat out of the water"

You can definitely say "grabbed the hat out of the water" - meaning you saw a hat in water and grabbed+lifted it.

"Held the hat out of the water" works and means you are preventing the hat from falling into the water by holding it.

"Touched the hat out of the water" is very likely to be parsed as "touched the hat that was out of the water" because *touching* means you've made contact with an object without trying to apply moving force to it.

Answer (score 1):

You hook the **hat** out of the water using the cane. One of the definitions of *hook* as a verb is 'to catch something using a hook'.

Comment: But when "you caught something", it doesn't mean you move it. For example, "I caught a rabbit out of a hole" or "I caught a rabbit and took it out of a hole"

Comment: When you _catch_ something like a wild animal or a floating object, you get it into your possession. Whether or not you move it is irrelevant.

Comment: @Tom Please answer banuyayi's comment below your question. There's some reason you want to know whether "hook" belongs to a certain category, and if we know the reason, we'll be able to tell you definitively

Comment: @gotube I updated my question